# Write to Teradata with python (aos_td)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, teradata

I have a Pandas dataframe that I want to insert into a Teradata table.

```
with aos_td.default_session(username='my_username', password='my_password', 
                            system='blah.blah.com') as session:

    session.executemany("""SCHEMA.TABLE(col1,col2,col3,col4) 
                        VALUES (?,?,?,?)""", df2)
```

It appears as though python is trying to include the index as a column and it doesn't match the number of columns in Teradata, throwing this error:

```
java.sql.SQLExceptionPyRaisable: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] 
[TeraJDBC 15.10.00.14] [Error 256] [SQLState HY000] 
Parameter index value 5 is outside the valid range of 1 through 4
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Perhaps insert just the values `df2.values`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the records without the index use

```
.to_records(index=False)
```

Here is the full code to write to Teradata from python with aos_td:

```
with aos_td.default_session(username='my_username', password='my_password', 
                        system='blah.blah.com') as session:

session.executemany("""SCHEMA.TABLE(col1,col2,col3,col4) 
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?)""", df2.to_records(index=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use SQLAlchemy for this.**

*Please kindly follow the Code after making connection with the Teradata:*

## Open Teradata Connection

```
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="App_Name", version="1.0",logConsole=False)
session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system='System_Details', 
username=getpass.getuser(), password=getpass.getpass());

%load_ext sql

try:
    %sql $connection_string
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

---

## Creating new Teradata Table from Python Dataframe..

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
```

## Writing Dataframe into Teradata

```
df.to_sql('dff2', con=engine)
engine.execute("SELECT * FROM dff2").fetchall()
```